# Print list of strings to file with newline inserted after n items

Tags: python, string, list, newline

I currently have a list of strings x:

```
[ '15.0000291159500048', '15.0000203137357904', '14.9999702802477710', '5.0000017127321428', '-5.0000029074634842', '0.0000000599304253', '0.0000001437028190', '-0.0000000724688421', '-0.0000000510019702' ]
```

Which I would like to print to a text file as a square by adding a newline after n elements where n = sqrt(len(x)) yielding a text file with output:

```
15.0000291159500048 15.0000203137357904 14.9999702802477710
5.0000017127321428 -5.0000029074634842 0.0000000599304253
0.0000001437028190 -0.0000000724688421 -0.0000000510019702
```

Anyone know of a clever way to accomplish this? Must I use a counter with modulus or can python do this innately more effeciently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`grouper` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the itertools documentation:

```
>>> data = [ '15.0000291159500048', '15.0000203137357904', '14.9999702802477710', '5.0000017127321428', '-5.0000029074634842', '0.0000000599304253', '0.0000001437028190', '-0.0000000724688421', '-0.0000000510019702' ]
>>> n = int(math.sqrt(len(data)))
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in grouper(data, n, ''))
15.0000291159500048 15.0000203137357904 14.9999702802477710
5.0000017127321428 -5.0000029074634842 0.0000000599304253
0.0000001437028190 -0.0000000724688421 -0.0000000510019702
```

Here is what `grouper()` looks like:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension and `str.join`:

```
In [26]: lis = [ '15.0000291159500048', '15.0000203137357904', '14.9999702802477
710', '5.0000017127321428', '-5.0000029074634842', '0.0000000599304253', '0.0000
001437028190', '-0.0000000724688421', '-0.0000000510019702' ]

In [27]: n = 3

In [28]: print "\n".join([' '.join(lis[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(0, len(lis), n)])

15.0000291159500048 15.0000203137357904 14.9999702802477710
5.0000017127321428 -5.0000029074634842 0.0000000599304253
0.0000001437028190 -0.0000000724688421 -0.0000000510019702
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [ '15.0000291159500048', '15.0000203137357904', '14.9999702802477710', '5.0000017127321428', '-5.0000029074634842', '0.0000000599304253', '0.0000001437028190', '-0.0000000724688421', '-0.0000000510019702' ]  
stepSize = int(sqrt(len(l)))
print '\n'.join([' '.join(l[i:i+stepSize]) for i in range(0, len(l), stepSize)])
```

Based on the answer for chunking python lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751478/2175939). We just choose a chunk size equal to the square root the length of the list. You could change this to round instead of truncate the square root.

The comprehension will retrieve sub-lists with the correct length, joining them together with a space. The result will be a list of strings showing your result separated by a space. We then join this together with a newline

Answer (score 0):

So this might be a bit nuts, but here's another approach.

`x = [ '15.0000291159500048', '15.0000203137357904', '14.9999702802477710',
          '5.0000017127321428', '-5.0000029074634842', '0.0000000599304253',
          '0.0000001437028190', '-0.0000000724688421', '-0.0000000510019702' ]
    s = math.sqrt(len(x))
    matrix = [[x[a+b] for z in xrange(int(s)) ] for y in range(0, len(x), int(s)) ]
    print "\n".join(
       map(lambda innerRow: " ".join(
         map(lambda item: str(item), innerRow)), matrix))`